# Access someone else's AWS S3 bucket with PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There's a AWS S3 bucket on a different AWS account than mine. He has granted access to an IAM user on my account, but I can't get my head around how I access this bucket with the PHP SDK.

```
<?php
$aws = S3Client::factory(array(
'key' => '**************',
'secret' => '********************************'
));

var_dump($aws->listBuckets()); die;
```

The above code only shows the buckets on my own account, but not the other one. The key and the secret are those of this specific user.

How do I access the delegated bucket on the other account?

Answer (score 1):

It won't show up in your `listBuckets()` results because even though you have access to it, it still doesn't belong to your account.

> How do I access the delegated bucket on the other account?

Have you tried any bucket-specific operations (e.g., `listObject()`, `headBucket()`)? If you have access, then these operations should work fine.